# this= ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller(id=23) cause app to force close when opened

Tags: android, eclipse, imageview, this, android-gridlayout

I figured out that the app shuts down when the below code is implemented....

```
ImageView characterImage;
int row=10, column=10;
gridLayout.removeAllViews();
gridLayout.setRowCount(row);
gridLayout.setColumnCount(column);

for(int r=0;r<=row;r++)
{
 for(int col=0;col<column;col++)
 {
  characterImage= new ImageView(this);
  characterImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);   
  GridLayout.LayoutParams param =new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
  param.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
  param.width = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
  param.rightMargin=1;
  param.leftMargin=1;
  param.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
  param.columnSpec=GridLayout.spec(col);
  param.rowSpec=GridLayout.spec(r);
  characterImage.setLayoutParams(param);
  gridLayout.addView(characterImage);
 }
}
```

During debugging the app closes at this line of code.....
    characterImage= new ImageView(this);

With an exception of
    this= ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller(id=23)

any idea how to fix this exception?

Comment: somehow the app force closes because "this" is being used. Is there any other way of creating a new ImageView without creating it in xml file? I don't know why but the debugger says that it is null.